# Adding pictures to a shared Dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox, images, file-sharing

Someone sent me a link to a shared folder to add some pictures but I can't figure out how to do it. I've never used Dropbox before and no matter how much I google I can only find information on how to create my **own** shared folder - which is not what I'm wanting to do.

I have signed up, downloaded the application and uploaded my selected photos to my Dropbox page. The shared folder link is nowhere on my home page and when I open the shared folder link via email, I just get a blank page with 'no photos' displayed and no option to upload them. I see that I am signed in, though, but other than that the only other links on the page is the Dropbox icon.

What do I need to do to add my pictures to this folder?

Comment: When you click the link in the mail about the shared folder, the folder should be added to your account, and be visible in the root of your Dropbox. Isn't it there?

Comment: Nope. Nada. I even clicked into the 'sharing' section and it says that I have no shared folders.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to sign into Dropbox/register with the email address that the folder was shared with.  After registering and signing in, you should be able to click the "Files" shortcut from the left sidebar.

This will load a directory listing. The shared folders are indicated by an icon with two people, as depicted in this partial screenshot:

[image: Note the dropbox sidebar shows your files shortcuts, and the shared folder is depicted by an icon with two people.]

Clicking on the shared folder should reveal any files/pics that the person sharing it already uploaded.  You can in turn upload files & pics to the same folder for that person to be able to access/see.